# Unity Text Event triggers in Editor but not in Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue with a C# game I'm developing in Unity. While in the editor text notifications with animations are triggered, but not when I build and run.

I checked the Output Log and got this.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at NarrativeLocation+<InitializePanel>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] 
  in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, 
  IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine_Auto_Internal(IEnumerator)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
NarrativeLocation:Update()
```

Code for NarrativeLocation.Update

```
void Update()
    {
        if (!popupIsPlaying && GameState.popupQueue.Count != 0)
        {
            int temp = GameState.popupQueue.Dequeue();
            StartCoroutine(InitializePanel(temp));
        }

        int num = 1;

        while(inZone)
        {
            if (this.gameObject.tag == "NarrativeEvent" + num)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
                {
                    Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Notification"));
                    Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("NarrativeEvent" + num));

                    Constants.GameState.popupQueue.Enqueue(num);
                }

                return;
            }
            num++;
        }
    }
```

Code for InitializePanel

```
IEnumerator InitializePanel(int num)
{
    popupIsPlaying = true;

    panel = GameObject.Find("Panel").GetComponent<PanelConfig>();
    currentEvent = JSONAssembly.RunJSONFactoryForScene(1);

    StartCoroutine(IntroAnimation());

    panel.characterIsTalking = true;
    panel.Configure(currentEvent.dialogues[num - 1]);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6f);

    StartCoroutine(ExitAnimation());

    Debug.Log("Event " + num + " destroyed");

    popupIsPlaying = false;

}

public IEnumerator IntroAnimation()
{
    panelAnimator.SetBool("IntroAnimationIn", true);
    yield break;
}

public IEnumerator ExitAnimation()
{
    panelAnimator.SetBool("IntroAnimationIn", false);
    yield break;

}
```

When I run the game, the panel pops up with no text. The Exit Animation doesn't seem to be called either.

The JSON Assembly Class.

```
namespace JSONFactory {
class JSONAssembly {

    private static Dictionary<int, string> _resourceList = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {1, "/Resources/GameScript.json"}
    };

    public static NarrativeEvent RunJSONFactoryForScene(int sceneNumber)
    {
        string resourcePath = PathForScene(sceneNumber);

        if (isValidJSON(resourcePath) == true)
        {
            string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + resourcePath);
            NarrativeEvent narrativeEvent = JsonMapper.ToObject<NarrativeEvent>(jsonString);

            return narrativeEvent;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("JSON is not valid");
        }
    }

    private static string PathForScene(int sceneNumber)
    {
        string resourcePathResult;

        if (_resourceList.TryGetValue(sceneNumber, out resourcePathResult))
        {
            return _resourceList[sceneNumber];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Scene not in resource list");
        }
    }

    private static bool isValidJSON(string path)
    {
        return (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".json") ? true : false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You will have to post some code for us to help, `NarrativeLocation:Update` would be the place to start.

Comment: @B.M. Added the code for NarrativeLocation:Upate.

Comment: What does `InitializePanel` look like?

Comment: @B.M. Hope this helps.

Comment: These are not the issues right here but `IntroAnimation` and `ExitAnimation` are a bit odd, why are they coroutines in the first place? You are also not awaiting them in `InitializePanel`, so you're scheduling them to run independently. I'd replace `StartCoroutine(IntroAnimation());` with `panelAnimator.SetBool("IntroAnimationIn", true);` for example, same for exit.

Comment: What's JSONAssembly? Where does it come from?

Comment: @B.M. I was using those in the past but removed code from them. Forgot that it the IEnumerators were not needed anymore.

Comment: @B.M. Added the JSONAssembly class

Comment: Your best bet would be to add `Debug.Log()` calls before each line in `InitializePanel` and figure out at which line this happens, that way you isolate the problem to one method only. Last I checked debug.log calls end up in the log file even in release, unless there's a flag somewhere you must set.

Comment: @B.M. Will do that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> While in the editor text notifications with animations are triggered,
>   but not when I build and run.

I can spot few possible reasons why your code is not working in a build. There could be more that I missed but see them below:

**1**. Where you are trying to load the json file from:

```
{1, "/Resources/GameScript.json"}
```

**A**. When reading from the Resources folder, you do not include the "Resources" in the path. The path is relative to the Resource folder.

**B**. Do not include the file extension names such as .txt, .jpeg, .mp3 in the path.

To fix both, *replace*:

```
{1, "/Resources/GameScript.json"}
```

**with**

```
{1, "GameScript"}
```

---

**2**. How you are currently reading the file:

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + resourcePath);
```

You are currently reading the file with `File.ReadAllText`. This will work in the Editor but not in a build because that's not how to read a file in the Resources folder.

Files in the Resources folder are read with the [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) API.

To fix this, *replace*:

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + resourcePath);
```

**with**

```
TextAsset txtAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(resourcePath);
string jsonString = txtAsset.text;
```

Make sure that the json file is placed in a folder named "Resources" in your project and that must be spelled correctly.

---

**Other issues will likely run into later on:**

Infinite loop:

The `while(inZone)` code doesn't have a way to to exit, If you ever run into that, you risk causing your program to freeze because there is no code to make `inZone` false in that loop. You have to find a way to re-write that code.

Answer (score 0):

In builds, you cannot use a resources path to load files at runtime using File.ReadAllText. Files in Resources/ directories get packaged into a proprietary packed-asset format during the build process and cannot be retrieved b path that way.

You must use the Resources api if you want to load files that way.

However, files placed in `Application.streamingAssetsPath` (aka `/Assets/StreamingAssets`) *CAN* be read at runtime this way. Files in that folder are preserved as is. They could be accessed by

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(
  Application.streamingAssetsPath, "/Path/To/file.json");

// assuming path is:
//   /Assets/StreamingAssets/Path/To/file.json
```

Resources is probably closer to what you want.

Alternatively, Unity imports json files (or any other text file for that matter) as `TextAssets`. You can reference these `TextAsset` files in the inspector like any other type of asset.

```
public class MyMono : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public TextAsset json;

    void Start() {
        Debug.Log(json.text);
    }
```